# Using Functions like Boolean() and count() with scrapy and xpath

Tags: python, xml, xpath, scrapy

so i was trying to use xpath function `boolean()` and extract true false response with scrapy
but all scrapy return is `u'0'`

whether or not its returning boolean true or boolean :false
scrapy always return
 `[<Selector xpath="boolean(.//*[@id='olp']/a)" data=u'0'>]`

basically this is my xpath

> boolean(.//*[@id='olp']/a)

when i run it using `firepath` it returns either true or false
if element exist it return true if it doesn't it returns false
but when doing through scrapy

```
print selector.xpath("boolean(.//*[@id='olp']/a)").extract()
```

can anyone here help me how i can get true or false directly through scrapy... i know i can do it through python by checking if element exist or not.. but my target here is to know if scrapy can process and return values of such function such as `boolean()` or `count()`

ps: i dont need exact answer to my scraping target .. i just need to know how or if can that be done..
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Be careful: Scrapy Selectors, while based on lxml, behave differently from lxml regarding results of boolean XPath expressions, or those returning numbers.

Let's use this sample HTML document to illustrate:

```
>>> html = '''<!DOCTYPE html>
... <html>
...   <head>
...     <title>This is a title</title>
...   </head>
...   <body>
...     <p>Hello world!</p>
...   </body>
... </html>'''
```

If you use lxml directly, you can test for example the existence of some elements like `<div>` or `<p>` in the document:

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> doc = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
>>> doc.xpath('boolean(//div)')
False
>>> doc.xpath('boolean(//p)')
True
```

lxml's `.xpath()` returns what you would expect: there are no `<div>` elements, but there is a `<p>`.

If you compare that with Scrapy selectors, calling `.xpath()` will return a `Selector` list. (This is independent of using boolean expressions or not.)

```
>>> import scrapy
>>> response = scrapy.Selector(text=html)
>>> response.xpath('boolean(//p)')
[<Selector xpath='boolean(//p)' data='1'>]
```

You need to call `.extract()` or `.extract_first()` (or the new `.get()` shortcut) to get "useful" data to work on. And what you get from `.extract()/.extract_first()/.get()` is string(s):

```
>>> response.xpath('boolean(//p)').extract()
['1']
>>> response.xpath('boolean(//p)').extract_first()
'1'
>>> response.xpath('boolean(//p)').get()
'1'
```

You see a `'1'` for XPath `true`. And you also get a `'0'` for XPath `false`:

```
>>> response.xpath('boolean(//div)').get()
'0'
```

In Python, `bool()` on a non-empty string will return `True`, whatever the string:

```
>>> bool(response.xpath('boolean(//p)').get())
True
>>> bool(response.xpath('boolean(//div)').get())
True
```

One workaround is to convert using `int()` in the "middle":

```
>>> bool(int(response.xpath('boolean(//p)').get()))
True
>>> bool(int(response.xpath('boolean(//div)').get()))
False
```

---

For XPath expressions returning numbers, like `count(...)`, lxml returns floats:

```
>>> doc.xpath('count(//div)')
0.0
>>> doc.xpath('count(//p)')
1.0
```

While Scrapy selectors with return a string representation of the float number:

```
>>> response.xpath('count(//div)').get()
'0.0'
>>> response.xpath('count(//p)').get()
'1.0'
```

So you want to pass the extracted string to `float()` before working on the result:

```
>>> float(response.xpath('count(//p)').get())
1.0
>>> float(response.xpath('count(//div)').get())
0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the xpath and evaluate it with python:

```
body = "<div class=something>hello!</div>"
sel = Selector(text=body)
elements = sel.xpath('//div[@class="something"]')
print(bool(elements))
# True
print(len(elements))
# 1
```